# JavaScript setInterval not being properly bound to correct closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, meteor

### Problem

Hi people, I'm reasonably new to JavaScript and I come from the very object-oriented world of Python and Java, that's my disclaimer.

There are two chunks of code below, alternative implementations, one in JavaScript, one in Coffeescript.  I am trying to run them on the server in a Meteor.js application.  The problem I am experiencing is when calling the function "setInterval" using the bound-method "this.printSomething" as my callback, once that callback is executed, it loses scope with the instance resulting in "this.bar" being undefined!  Can anyone explain to me why either the JavaScript or the coffescript code isn't working?

### JavaScript Implementation

```
function Foo(bar) {
  this.bar = bar;

  this.start = function () {
    setInterval(this.printSomething, 3000);
  }

  this.printSomething = function() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
}

f = new Foo(5);
f.start();
```

### Coffeescript Implementation

```
class foo
    constructor: (bar) ->
        @bar = bar

    start: () ->
        Meteor.setInterval(@printSomething, 3000)

    printSomething: () ->
        console.log @bar

x = new foo 0
x.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

You lose your context of `Foo` in the setInterval callback. You can use [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the context to something like this to set the context for the callback function reference back to `Foo` instance.

```
setInterval(this.printSomething.bind(this), 3000);
```

With the call

```
setInterval(this.printSomething, 3000);
```

The callback method gets the global context (window in case of web or global in case of tenants like node) so you don't get property `bar` there since `this` refers to the global context.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RNhwj/)**

or just

```
 this.printSomething = function() {
     console.log(bar); //you can access bar here since it is not bound to the instance of Foo
  }
```

Comment: And, for CoffeeScript, a function can be bound with [the "*fat arrow*"](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) -- `printSomething: () =>`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks... not familiar with coffee syntax. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try creating a closure to capture the `this`. Like this:

```
var self = this;
this.start = function () {
    setInterval(function(){
       self.printSomething();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a function, you get a new scope in javascript. You can inherit from the parent scope, but the value of `this` changes. In coffeescript, you can use the fat arrow (which looks like it is going to be part of ecmascript 6) which basically retains a reference to `this` before going into the new scope.

```
class foo
    constructor: (bar) ->
        @bar = bar

    start: () =>
        Meteor.setInterval(@printSomething, 3000)

    printSomething: () =>
        console.log @bar

x = new foo 0
x.start()
```

The standard way to handle this kind of thing in javascript is to create a reference to `this` at the point you want to refer to, and then use the reference in your out of scope calls...

```
function Foo(bar) {

  // make reference to `this` at the point
  // where you want to use it from
  self = this;

  self.bar = bar;

  self.start = function () {
    setInterval(self.printSomething, 3000);
  }

  self.printSomething = function() {
    console.log(self.bar);
  }
}

f = new Foo(5);
f.start();
```